# How to check if a QWidget is closed in QMainWindow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two files:

main.py

```
from un import Ui_Form
...
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()
     self.show_btn.clicked.connect(self.show_btn_fun)
     ...
   def double_opening(self):
     #this method passes data for my requests to self.window 
     for idx in self.tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes():
        row_number = idx.row()
        column_number = idx.column()
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.text_to_change = format(self.tableView.model().index(row_number, 2).data())
        self.ui = Ui_Form(self.text_to_change)
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.window.show()

    def show_btn_fun(self):  
        #show the entire existing table
...
def main():
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
window = ExampleApp()  
window.show() 
app.exec_()
if __name__ == '__main__':  
main()
```

and un.py:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
   def setupUi(self, Form):
      Form.setObjectName("Form")
      ...
      self.button_changes_confirm.clicked.connect(self.changes)
      self.button_changes_confirm.clicked.connect(Form.close)
      ...
   def changes(self):
      #makes my update to the database
```

after I click "button_changes_confirm", the data in my database is updated

but to see that the data has been updated, I need to call the "show_bug_fun" method with  "show_btn" button

how to call the "show_btn_fun" method when "self.window" is closing?

Comment: I see a for loop in `double_opening`, are you sure that you want to show a window for *each* selected index? In any case, you should use a QDialog for that, since it would make things easier. Also, you should not edit files generated by pyuic. Read [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Comment: i show window for selected index. 
"Also, you should not edit files generated by pyuic" - why?

Comment: There are various reasons: 1. whenever you have to change the UI in designer you have to rebuild the file, so you either risk to overwrite and loose your modifications, or you have to merge the changes everytime (which means that you will potentially introduce bugs due to typos, wrong copy/paste or forgotten functions); 2. there's no benefit in changing those files, since sooner or later you need to subclass anyway; 3. it usually leads to misunderstandings and unexpected behavior about the object structure; 4. they are not Qt based classes (QObject), so they cannot have signals and properties;

Comment: 5. since they are not Qt classes, they don't allow overriding of Qt widgets methods so you need to subclass a Qt widget anyway; 6. they don't keep a reference to the widget they are built on, so implementing functions that require that reference make things unnecessarily complex. Editing those files (or mimicking their behavior, or "merging" their functions) is considered a bad practice because it does not provide any real benefit and only introduces the above problems. You should consider them just as "resource files" that are used by your program and used as they are, nothing more.

Comment: not sure about it, but could redefine your Ui_Form(object) ---> def closeEvent(self, event): to call your method. See here as example https://learndataanalysis.org/example-of-how-to-use-the-qwidget-close-event-pyqt5-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

here my attempt, calling a button when form is closed:

```
mainwin.py  (main window) :
```

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 30, 261, 131))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 220, 261, 131))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 29))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

a form copied from  https://gitpress.io/u/1155/pyqt-example-ui_form

```
form3      :
```

```
"""

copied from https://gitpress.io/u/1155/pyqt-example-ui_form

"""

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        
        Form.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(545, 471)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.easingCurvePicker = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.easingCurvePicker.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.easingCurvePicker.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.easingCurvePicker.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 120))
        self.easingCurvePicker.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.easingCurvePicker.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.easingCurvePicker.setProperty("isWrapping", False)
        self.easingCurvePicker.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.easingCurvePicker.setSelectionRectVisible(False)
        self.easingCurvePicker.setObjectName("easingCurvePicker")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.easingCurvePicker, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.lineRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineRadio.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.lineRadio.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineRadio.setChecked(True)
        self.lineRadio.setObjectName("lineRadio")
        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(Form)
        self.buttonGroup.setObjectName("buttonGroup")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.lineRadio)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineRadio, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.circleRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.circleRadio.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.circleRadio.setObjectName("circleRadio")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.circleRadio)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.circleRadio, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.groupBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.groupBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.formLayout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtWidgets.QFormLayout.AllNonFixedFieldsGrow)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.periodSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.groupBox)
        self.periodSpinBox.setEnabled(False)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.periodSpinBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.periodSpinBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.periodSpinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.periodSpinBox.setMinimum(-1.0)
        self.periodSpinBox.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.periodSpinBox.setProperty("value", -1.0)
        self.periodSpinBox.setObjectName("periodSpinBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.periodSpinBox)
        self.amplitudeSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.groupBox)
        self.amplitudeSpinBox.setEnabled(False)
        self.amplitudeSpinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.amplitudeSpinBox.setMinimum(-1.0)
        self.amplitudeSpinBox.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.amplitudeSpinBox.setProperty("value", -1.0)
        self.amplitudeSpinBox.setObjectName("amplitudeSpinBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.amplitudeSpinBox)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.overshootSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.groupBox)
        self.overshootSpinBox.setEnabled(False)
        self.overshootSpinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.overshootSpinBox.setMinimum(-1.0)
        self.overshootSpinBox.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.overshootSpinBox.setProperty("value", -1.0)
        self.overshootSpinBox.setObjectName("overshootSpinBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.overshootSpinBox)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.graphicsView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.graphicsView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 1, 1, 1, 1)


        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1") 
        self.pushButton_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 390, 120, 60))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
 
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Easing curves"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Path type"))
        self.lineRadio.setText(_translate("Form", "Line"))
        self.circleRadio.setText(_translate("Form", "Circle"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Properties"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Period"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Overshoot"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Amplitude"))
        
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("Form", "Close Here"))
```

my code , `main.py` :

```
import sys 

from mainwin import Ui_MainWindow

from form3b import Ui_Form

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets



class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.show()   
        
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_Pressed)
        
    def pushButton_1_Pressed(self):
        
        self.close()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        
        MainWindow.pushButton_2_Pressed(self)
        
        print('closing')
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_Pressed)
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_2_Pressed)
        
        

        
    def pushButton_1_Pressed(self):
        
        self.x = Form()
        
        # self.x.show() # its in Form init already
    
    
    def pushButton_2_Pressed(self):
        
        print('button 2 pressed')
        

                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

pressing upper PushButton open the form, when closing the form (X on the right up corner) get `print('closing')` and MainWindow lower PushButton `print('button 2 pressed')`, pressing PushButton on the form ("Close Here") its like closing the form.